# Processing NSDictionary Data

Tags: ios, web-services, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

Below is data from the web service. I would like to combine the key and pair into array. Basically the data i received is array of dictionary with key value pair, but again a key 'records' is array of dictionary. How to process this ? I had given my desired output below. It would be great if you someone can help me. Please note, 'records' can be any 1, 2 or more (for illustration purpose, i had given the record count as 1 and 2)

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7feb44c0e400>(
{
    a = "string";
    b = "string";
    records =     (
                {
            aa = "first array's first record";
            bb = "first array's first record";
            cc = "first array's first record";
        }
    );
    c = "somevalue";
    d = "some value";
    e = "some value";
},


{
    a = "string";
    b = "string";
    records =     (
                {
            aa = "second array's first record";
            bb = "second array's first record";
            cc = "second array's first record";
        },
                {
            aa = "second array's second record";
            bb = "second array's second record";
            cc = "second array's second record";
        }
    );
    c = "some value";
    d = "some value";
    e = "some value";
}
)
```

I want the output like the below

```
  {
a = "string";
b = "string";
aa = "first array's first record";
bb = "first array's first record";
cc = "first array's first record";
c = "somevalue";
d = "some value";
e = "some value";
},

{
a = "string";
b = "string";
aa = "second array's first record";
bb = "second array's first record";
cc = "second array's first record";
c = "some value";
d = "some value";
e = "some value";
},

{
a = "string";
b = "string";
aa = "second array's second record";
bb = "second array's second record";
cc = "second array's second record";
c = "some value";
d = "some value";
e = "some value";
}
```

**Tried**

```
NSDictionary *receivedDictionary = self.responseDictionary;
  NSArray *finalArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
  NSMutableArray *array;
  for (int i=0; i<[receivedDictionary count]; i++) {
     array = [[receivedDictionary valueForKey:@"records"]objectAtIndex:i];

  }
  finalArray = [array arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];
```

**Edited - Output**

```
{
        a = "some string";
        b = "some string";
        records =         (
                        {
                aa = 75;
                bb = "some string";
                cc = "some string ";
            },
                        {
                aa = 76;
                bb = "some string";
                cc = "some string";
            }
        );
        c = "some value";
        d = "some value";
        e = "some value";
    }
)
```

If you see the above actual json object, there are 75 and 76 in aa, but only one value is saved in the final array as given below.

```
{
        a = "some string";
        b = "some string";
        c = "some value";
        d = "some value";
        aa = 76;
        bb = "some string"";
        cc = "some string";
        e = "some string";
    }
)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I was able to get the data of 'records', but not sure how to combine the all the key into array . Please check my edited version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want, you will end up with an array containing a dictionary for every record object. (Assuming that `inputArray` is an `NSArray` in the format of your question.) I've tried to comment what is happening on each line.

```
//First we initialize an empty array to store all the values.   
NSMutableArray *finalOutput = [NSMutableArray array];
//Next we loop through every dictionary in your input array.
for (NSDictionary *outerDict in inputArray) {
    //Make a copy of that dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *outerCopy = [outerDict mutableCopy];
    //but remove the records object as we'll add that back again in the next step
    [outerCopy removeObjectForKey:@"records"];
    //Now we loop through all the records for outerDict
    for (NSDictionary *record in outerDict[@"records"]) {
        //Make a mutable copy
        NSMutableDictionary *flattenedDict = [record mutableCopy];
        //Add back the values from the outerCopy
        [flattenedDict addEntriesFromDictionary:outerCopy];
        //And add this final flattened dictionary to the output array
        [finalOutput addObject:flattenedDict];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this accordingly to my desired output and based on the data provided ?

Comment: I've added example output, it's identical to the output you wanted, given that you pass in an array the same format as in your question.

Comment: Yeah, the OP you have provided is what i want, but can you provide the code in detail ? where do i need to set the value for 'a','b','c'...'aa',bb' etc ? Can you please post the detailed code as i couldn't follow the piece of code you provided ?

Comment: I've commented each line, but I'm not sure what you mean by setting the values a, b, c, they will all get copied across into `flattenedDict`.

Comment: Thank you James. This works Great ! Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *jsonArray; // Your Json array Object
    for(NSDictionary * outerDictionary in jsonArray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *objectDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [objectDictionary setValue:outerDictionary[@"a"] forKey:@"a"];

        [objectDictionary setValue:outerDictionary[@"b"] forKey:@"b"];



 NSArray *records = outerDictionary[@"record"];
    for (NSDictionary *record in records) {

            [objectDictionary setValue:record[@"aa"] forKey:@"aa"];

            [objectDictionary setValue:record[@"bb"] forKey:@"bb"];

            [objectDictionary setValue:record[@"cc"] forKey:@"cc"];

        }
        [objectDictionary setValue:outerDictionary[@"c"] forKey:@"c"];

        [objectDictionary setValue:outerDictionary[@"d"] forKey:@"c"];

        [objectDictionary setValue:outerDictionary[@"e"] forKey:@"e"];
        [finalArray addObject:objectDictionary];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is working, except one problem, when there are 2 records belong to same dictionary, then only one is saved. See my edited section. Some when there are two different top most dictionary contains one record, then the array has 3 times, it should have only 2.

Comment: Thanks Amit. This will also be helpful for some cases. Thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through each dictionary as :

```
for (int i=0; i<[records count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [records objectAtIndex:i];
        [dictValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"aa"]];
        [dictValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"bb"]];
        [dictValues addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"cc"]];

    }
```